# Special cases of the Stark-Heegner theorem with simple proofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

The **Stark-Heegner theorem** states that the ring of integers of the quadratic number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$, where $m$ is a squarefree negative integer, is a principal ideal domain, iff
$$m\in\{-1,-2,-3,-7,-11,-19,-43,-67,-163\}$$
I am looking for special cases of this theorem (including references where I can find them), which can be proven with elementary number theory or not-too-complicated algebraic number theory.

This is what I have so far:

- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ is a PID for $m\in\{-1,-2,-3,-7,-11\}$ (It is easy to prove, that this rings are norm-Euclidean and that Euclidean rings are PIDs)
- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ is a PID for $m\in\{-19,-43,-67,-163\}$ (Either prove, hat the norm is a Dedekind–Hasse norm for these rings, or that, if Euler's prime generating polynomial $x^2+x+q$ generates primes for $x=0,\dots q-1$, then  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1-4q})$ is a PID)
- If $m\not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $m<-2$, then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ is not a PID (Again, there are several proofs, one of them is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310721/conclude-that-mathbbz-sqrtn-is-not-a-ufd))

Does anyone know any other simple result in the above spirit, particulary for proving that some rings are *not* PIDs? Maybe something like a proof, that there are only finitely many PIDs, maybe even an upper bound for $m$, or the fact that $m\equiv 1\bmod{8}$ does not work, or maybe some other restriction on $m$?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** All Heegner numbers are prime. Maybe, there is some argument, why it won't work for composite numbers?

Comment: I think you are aware of it, but I'm not sure how to interpret your last sentence, so to be sure: the case $m \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ is settled by the fact that $2$ is not a prime then, and for $m < -7$, it is irreducible.

Comment: Well, this was actually meant as a question, as I saw this in an other more difficult context. I didn't think about this easy solution. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to ping me when you find something simple for the $m \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ case.

Comment: Haha, well that would be nice.

Comment: Well, I should have written __any__ $m \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ case. Some may be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of easy cases. If $m$ is even, or if $m \equiv -1 \bmod 4$, then $2$ ramifies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$. But $2$ is not of the form $a^2+|m| b^2$, except for $m=-1$ and $m=-2$.  So we can limit ourselves to $m \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. As pointed out above, we can also assume $m \not \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. So we are down to $m \equiv -5 \bmod 8$. This means that the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ is $a+b(1+\sqrt{m})/2$, with norm function $a^2 + ab + \frac{|m|+1}{4} b^2$. (Of course, $m$ is negative, but I think a lot of these formulas are more readable with $|m|$ instead of $-m$ because it makes the sign immediately visually clear.)

In particular, if $b \neq 0$, the norm $N(a+b(1+\sqrt{m})/2) \geq \frac{|m|+1}{4}$.

First of all, this explains why $m$ must be prime. If $m$ is an odd, square-free composite, then there is a prime $p$ dividing $m$ with $p \leq |m|/5$. This prime $p$ ramifies, so there is a prime ideal $\pi$ with $N(\pi) = p$. Since $p \leq m/5 < \frac{|m|+1}{4}$, the ideal $\pi$ can't be principal.

Also, suppose that $p$ is an odd prime with $\left( \frac{m}{p} \right) =1$ and $p < (|m|+1)/4$. Then, $p$ splits into $\pi \bar{\pi}$ and the same argument as the above paragraph shows that $\pi$ can't be principal.

**Summary** Any counterexample must have $|m|$ a prime, $m \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, and must have $\left( \frac{m}{p} \right) = -1$ for $p < \frac{|m|+1}{4}$.

I can't find any $m$ more negative than $-163$ which passes this test, searching through the first $50,000$ primes.  Nothing even comes close. Define $r(m)$ to be the least odd prime $p$ for which $\left( \frac{m}{p} \right) = 1$. A PID would have $r(m)/|m| > 0.25$; the largest value I can find after $163$ is $r(-193)/193 = 11/193 \approx 0.057$. In case you want to do some computations yourself, here is a bit of Mathematica code:

```
FirstSplit[m_] :=
   (i = 2; While[KroneckerSymbol[m, Prime[i]] == -1, i++]; Prime[i])

SplitRatio[m_] := FirstSplit[-m]/m
```

Comment: Quite impressive, thank you!

Comment: Since it seems to be possible to find an arbitrary big lower bound for $m$ with your computational method (as long as there are no counterexamples to $r(m)/|m|>0.25$), any upper bound would complete the proof of the theorem, so this suggests, that there is no simple proof for an upper bound for $m$.

Comment: The problem of the first quadratic residue is famously hard but does have some good bounds; see http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/ . Regarding the first prime residue, all I could find quickly was this unanswered question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421188/smallest-prime-p-with-n-a-quadratic-residue-mod-p

Comment: [Here](http://www.yau-awards.org/English/E/E62%20-A%20research%20on%20the%20minimum%20prime%20quadratic%20residue.pdf) is a bound, but it's derived from Heegner's theorem.

Comment: More precise: The paper shows, that for $p>163$, the least prime quadratic residue modulo $p$ is bounded by $\sqrt{p}$. The result is derived from Heegner's theorem, but nevertheless it shows, that there is no counterexample to $r(m)/|m|>0.25$ for $|m|>163$, am I right?